# How can I convert the ISO codes to country names in my MySQL table?

Tags: java, mysql, json

I found on GitHub a [project](https://github.com/mwgg/Airports) that JSON which contains a list of 28K+ airport(ISO code, name, status...) which is great and I'm gonna use it in my Java project later on. I converted to a .sql file and imported it in my MySQL database as a new table.

My only problem is the ISO codes, I was looking for one with the country names not the codes themselves. So I added a new column to my MySQL table called country that would eventually contains the country name. So how could i do that? Is there a project or some code I could use to automatically convert the ISO codes to the country name without having to manually do that for the whole 6822 rows in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the JSON data](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all) for countries and their codes. (They have some more APIs)
You can use [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) to create a HashMap from the JSON data and use it to get the country name by it's code.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely just [ISO 3166 Country Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166) data which is readily available in a variety of formats.

Comment: Sorry but aren't the ISO 3166 just codes? How can convert those codes to the country names?

Comment: Download a 3166-1 lookup table in the format of your choosing. This converts things like "US" to "United States of America" and so on. Some better versions have shorter names for countries like "KP" is not "Democratic People's Republic of Korea" but "North Korea". You have thousands of options to choose from since this is a ratified standard.